# Change values to string

Tags: java, android, database, string

I am new to java and coding. I have created an app that asks the user to register their username and password to be able to log in. I have this piece of code:

```
 EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
 EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
 EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword2);

 String usernamestr = username.getText().toString();
 String passwordstr = password.getText().toString();
 String password2str = password2.getText().toString();
```

It all works fine. I am just wondering why it has to be changed to a String to save to the database?

Comment: "***I am just wondering why it has to be changed to a String to save to the database?***" otherwise you would be saving an [object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)

Comment: EditText.getText returns Editable and not String.

Answer (score 2):

Because String has an equivalent in the database typing system (e.g. `varchar`) and the JDBC driver will be able to translate it to that type.
EditText doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If your database is using `varchar` to save username and password then you need to convert to `strings`, because `String` in java are similar to `varchar` in DB. Whereas there is no object in DB which corresponds to `EditText` in Java